# Mongoose web server getting current working threads

Tags: c++, c, linux, mongoose-web-server

I am starting mongoose web server with x threads. 
Is there a way that I can log when all x threads are busy so I can increase the thread count if required ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible without changing the code of Mongoose. I would, for example, change the `static void worker_thread(struct mg_context *ctx)` function in `mongoose.c`:

1. While the worker thread is inside the while loop `while (consume_socket(ctx, &conn->client))`, you could consider the worker thread as busy.
2. After `close_connection(conn);` the worker thread is free for processing a new event in the socket queue.

You can use that point for counting the number of busy threads.

Answer (score 1):

As diewie suggested, you can:

- add "int num_idle" to the struct mg_context
- in consume_socket, do:

  ```
  ctx->num_idle++;

  // If the queue is empty, wait. We're idle at this point.
  while (ctx->sq_head == ctx->sq_tail && ctx->stop_flag == 0) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&ctx->sq_full, &ctx->mutex);
  }

  ctx->num_idle--;
  assert(ctx->num_idle >= 0);
  if (ctx->num_idle == 0) {
    ... your code ...
  }
  ```

Comment: You should use an interlocked increment to avoid errors in that count.